# How can I demux audio from video playing on HTML browser and mux it back to play

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, video-processing, video-encoding, html5-audio

I have a requirement where I could able to demux audio from the video that was being played in the html browser and want to apply some effects to audio and mux back to play the video with this change. Any could point me to the proper sources or examples would be really great help.

Regards
symadept

Comment: you  want to do it on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg http://ffmpeg.org/ or gstreamer can be used.